# Why some commands cause an error relative to the preceding command?

Tags: python, pandas, theory

This is a pandas question.

Try to copy this in Jupyter Notebook:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
        index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
        columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])

        df
```

```
In [2]: df.pop('shield') # Return as series.
```

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(df.pop('shield')) # Return as DataFrame.
```

Then inverse it to the sequence of

> In[1]
>
>  In[3]
>
>  In[2]

**Why the 3rd Out[-] always cause an error?**

I oftentimes encounter this kinds of error. Is this a cache issue? Redundancy? What is the reason why such error occurs?

Comment: you can't pop twice, pop removes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code generate expected error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
        index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
        columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
```

Here [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) take column `shield` from original Dataframe, create Series and drop from original:

```
a = df.pop('shield') # Return as series.
print (a)
cobra         2
viper         5
sidewinder    8
Name: shield, dtype: int64
```

So no column in `df` after `pop`:

```
print (df)
            max_speed
cobra               1
viper               4
sidewinder          7
```

So failed get column `shield`, because not exist in `df`:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('shield')) # Return as DataFrame.
print (b)
KeyError: 'shield'
```

Answer (score 2):

`pop` removes the series from the dataframe while returning it.

You can't call it twice in sequence no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

in 2 nd line you are deleting shield
in third lien you are pop again
removing 2nd and code will work as expected

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
        index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
        columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])


pd.DataFrame(df.pop('shield'))
```